# Magento 2 explanation for special Keywords on hove in description

Tags: magento2, plugin

is there an Add-on/Plugin where i can define special keywords and explanations and Magento will create an "on-hover" explanation in every description?

example:
http://www.vango.de/camping-trekkingzelte/trekkingzelte/trekking-pro/829/zenith-pro-100-anthracite?c=40 
See the word "Wassersäule"?

I want to organize those keywords centrally and don't want to edit every description. 
Some tips? I could not find any on google.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your abilities to create a simple Magento module. You could inject a library such as this https://github.com/PebbleRoad/glossarizer and then create a custom table in the DB or file to store your JSON Object.

Comment: this library looks pretty interesting. I will look if i can get the time to implement this as a module. Thanks for the advice :-)